# Rails HTML Multi Layered IF checking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, ruby-on-rails-6

I am working on a layout that requires a couple of checks to the database, but I cannot figure out the logic on the IF statement. I have a `People` table where each record holds a `Position` field. There are times that specific positions will be held by two people. In which cases they want to be Co-Position. So I current am listing said Position on my page with:

```
<li>
    <% @people.each do |person| %>
        <% if person.position == 'Office1' %>
            <div class="image">
                <%= link_to(person_path) do %>
                    <%= image_tag("profiles/#{person.uname}S.jpg") %>
                <% end %>
            </div>
            <div class="body2">
                <h4>Office</h4> 
                <%= link_to(person_path) do %>
                    <h5><%= person.fname %> <%= person.lname %></h5>
                <% end %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
</li>
```

Now within that I need to run a check at `<h4>Office</h4>` to see if another record holds `Office2`, but if I place an IF statement around the `H4` tags will it be checking the already fetched record or will it check the entirety of the Person database? Do I need to do this check first and then do an IF/Then or can this be done in a more streamlined way?

Basically I need to check if Office2 is present somewhere in the Position field, and if it is I need the H4 to read Co-Office, else I need it to read Office.

Answer (score 0):

If your condition is `if person.position.include?('Office2')` then no, it won't touch the database again. The `person` object is loaded with all its attributes.

Comment: That is what I thought, so will I need to do a branching IF/THEN statement and check for that first before I load the record with Office1? Or is there a better way to do that?

Comment: It's not completely clear what you are attempting to do. If you would update the code with the logic you need, it would be much clearer. Specifically, the sentence "before I load the record with Office1" does not seem to fit in…